# Problem with images and JSP

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I am not able to see any images in my JSP page. I get the error

> Resource interpreted as image but transferred with MIME type text/html.

What does it mean? What is solution?

Comment: Posting some of your code would be helpful.

Comment: It means the image data is transferred with the wrong "data type" (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mime_type). How do you serve images? Do you have an extra servlet that processes these requests? What has this to do with JavaScript?

Comment: too low acceptance. Mime was set incorrectly. Short heading, long description is good, not the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the client requested what it thought was an image and received what the server claimed was an HTML document.

I suspect that:

- You have the wrong URLs for the images and
- The servers *404 Not Found* error page is being sent with a *200 OK* status code.

Answer (score 2):

The response you have sent to browser contains MIME type as  `text/html` but you have transferred image data.

If you are sending image by response.write(..); from servlet or producing it from jsp make sure its MIME type should be `Content-type: image/png` [png if format is png , jpg . .[refer more](http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp) and choose appropriate]